# Hiding the debugger from a third party executable

Tags: visual-studio-2010, debugging

I have a DLL written in Visual C++ that works with a third party program (through a standardized interface) and I need know whether or not that program is calling my functions correctly, if at all.

Normally I can just choose the executable as the debug entry command, but this particular executable can somehow detect that there's a debugger attached and refuses to run.

It gives the following message:

> ---------------------------
>   PRISM 8.1.1
>   ---------------------------
>   Debugger found
>
> A debugger has been found running in your system.
>
> Please, unload it from memory and restart your program !
>
> Please, visit: www.prism-astro.com to get support.
>   ---------------------------
>   OK
>   ---------------------------

How can I hide the debugger from the program.
Note that I'm only trying to debug my DLL and not the third party program, so I don't think there should be legal issues.

Comment: first start your application then `Debug -> Attach to Process` ?

Comment: I mainly want the debugger to hit the break points I set in my DLL. I don't know if attaching preserves that property.

Comment: it does but you could just set them again if it didnt anyway

Comment: Okay I just tried attaching the debugger, the executable somehow detected it anyway.